# How to remove dead actors from Akka router?

Tags: java, akka

In my application I have one server node and several worker nodes with one actor one each. Each actor sends the initial message to the server, and server adds it to Router. But when client becomes dead (programm is killed for example), the number of routees in the router stays the same.

How can clean the router from the dead actors?

Comment: Not sure I understood here, can you be clearer/more specific ?

Comment: You should look into clustering.  You get this functionality for free basically with clustering.  Check out this link and the section on Cluster Aware Routers: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/java/cluster-usage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka have some lifecycle methods that you can override. For example on `preStart` method you can register your actor to router and on `postStop` you can remove it.

```
override def preStart() {
  router ! AddMe
}

override def postStop() {
  router ! RemoveMe
}
```

Akka has good [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actor-lifecycle) about actor's lifecycle.